# Seleccionar fecha y cargar el valor automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, date

Que tal, lo que trato de dar a entender es que necesito que el usuario seleccione una fecha y sin darle click al botón me de la fecha seleccionada, he buscado eventos en JS pero ando un poco perdido, alguien me pudiera asesorar por favor, muchas gracias..

Comparto el código:

Tengo una fecha donde el usuario va a elegir:

```html
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<label>FECHA: </label> 
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required> 
</div>
```

Necesito saber la fecha que eligió para saber que día de la semana seleccionó, pero necesito que lo haga al momento de seleccionar la fecha ya que ahorita lo hace hasta que le da clic en el botón, pero necesito hacerlo sin necesidad de dar clic en el botón.

Después de la fecha sigue este código, que lo que me hace es comparar su hora de entrada o salida, dependiendo del caso... Espero darme a entender..

Comment: Debe agregar su codigo, para que sea mas facil ayudar

Comment: Seria mucho más sencillo que nos dieras más información de lo que quieres hacer y lo que tienes hasta ahora, creo que la función que buscas es `onBlur` te sugiero leer la documentación https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: @IvanBotero Ya actualice la publicación..

Comment: @M.Gress voy a estudiar lo que me acabas de pasar, muchas gracias,... Ya actualice la pregunta..

Comment: Hasta que le da click a qué botón?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como quieres que sea justo despues de seleccionar la fecha, te recomiendo el evento `onChange`, que se activa cuando el valor del input ha cambiado. (el `onBlur` que te recomiendan en los comentarios es cuando sales del elemento)

El `input date` a parte del `value` tiene `valueAsDate` que te retorna un obj `Date`.

Con él puedes sacar el dia (numerico) con <strike>`getDay()`</strike> con `getUTCDay()`

Haciendo un pequeño array con los dias de la semana, y el indice que devuelve el `getUTCDay()` podemos saber qué día es.

Ejemplo:

```js
var dias = ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];


function diaSemana() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
    alert( "Día: " + dias[x.valueAsDate.getUTCDay()]);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<label>FECHA: </label> 
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" onchange="diaSemana();" required> 
</div>
```